# How to place a div at top center position of a page using CSS?

Tags: css

I am not able to place a div at the top center of a page. I am using CSS for this but nothing works here.

```css
#loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  clear: left;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="loader" style='display: none'><img src='img/basic/loader4.gif' /></div>
</body>
```

I had already given 2 hours on this but still not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remove `display:none;` from your div with id=loader & add `text-align:center;` to it

```
#loader{  
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    clear:left;
    height:auto;
    z-index: 0;
    text-align:center;/* Add This*/
}​
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/FCEhD/

Answer (score 2):

You need a specific width for the div, otherwise it will use all the available with, and the margin has no effect. Example:

```
#loader{  
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify `width` property if you want to use `margin: 0 auto;`.

If you don't know width just add `display: table` property and it will works.

```
#out {
   display: table;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above example everyone is assuming he wants 'full width'.

This works within an absolute full width / height parent container but constraints the width automatically to only the content width

Parent Container

```
display: block; 
position: absolute;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: solid thin red;
```

Child Container

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
top:0;
transform: translateX(50%);
padding-left:.5em;
padding-right:.5em;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
right:50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#loader{  
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="loader" style='display: none' align="center">`

press ctrl+space am not sure about the syntax
and in css margin and padding has to set 0

Answer (score 0):

```
#loader
{
    position: absolute;
    width: xxpx;
    height: xxpx;
    margin:0px auto ;

}
```

or u can use

```
margin-left:xx;  and `margin-top:0px;`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#loader {
    display: none;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: [a number] px;
}
```

of course you should also note the browser cache. clear cache of your browser and test again